# Allowing for deviations in exact values during matrix multiplication, python

Tags: python, matrix

I need to solve this:

Check if `AT * n * A = n`, where A is the test matrix, AT is the transposed test matrix  and n = `[[1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0],[0,0,0,-1]]`.

I don't know how to check for equality due to the numerical errors in the float multiplication. How do I go about doing this?

Current code:

```
def trans(A):
 n = numpy.matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0],[0,0,0,-1]])
 c = numpy.matrix.transpose(A) * n * numpy.matrix(A)
```

Have then tried

```
>if c == n:
     return True
```

I have also tried assigning variables to every element of matrix and then checking that each variable is within certain limits.

Comment: Are you using pure Python or a module such as `numpy` for matrix multiplication?

Comment: Please include a code example to show what you have tried/what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the way that numerical-precision limitations are overcome is by allowing for some *epsilon* (or error-value) between the actual value and expected value that is still considered 'equal'. For example, I might say that some value a is equal to some value b if they are within plus/minus 0.01. This would be implemented in python as:

```
def float_equals(a, b, epsilon):
    return abs(a-b)<epsilon
```

Of course, for matrixes entered as lists, this isn't quite so simple. We have to check if all values are within the epsilon to their partner. One example solution would be as follows, assuming your matrices are standard python lists:

```
from itertools import product # need this to generate indexes

def matrix_float_equals(A, B, epsilon):
    return all(abs(A[i][j]-B[i][j])<epsilon for i,j in product(xrange(len(A)), repeat = 2))
```

`all` returns `True` iff all values in a list are `True` (list-wise `and`). `product` effectively dot-products two lists, with the `repeat` keyword allowing easy duplicate lists. Therefore given a `range` repeated twice, it will produce a list of tuples for each index. Of course, this method of index generation assumes square, equally-sized matrices. For non-square matrices you have to get more creative, but the idea is the same.

However, as is typically the way in python, there are libraries that do this kind of thing for you. Numpy's [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) does exactly this; compares two numpy arrays for equality element-wise within some tolerance. If you're working with matrices in python for numeric analysis, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is really the way to go, I would get familiar with its basic API.

Comment: `array_equal` compares without tolerance; [`allcose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) compares with tolerance.

Comment: @Frxstrem whoops, you're absolutely right, I mis-read the doc's mention of `allclose` as part of `array_equal`.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are numpy arrays or matrices of the same shape, then you can use [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
if numpy.allclose(a, b): # a is approximately equal to b
  # do something ...
```

This checks that for all i and all j, |a<sub>ij</sub> - b<sub>ij</sub>| < ε<sub>a</sub> for some absolute error ε<sub>a</sub> (by default 10<sup>-5</sup>) and that |a<sub>ij</sub> - b<sub>ij</sub>| < |b<sub>ij</sub>| ε<sub>r</sub> for some relative error ε<sub>r</sub> (by default 10<sup>-8</sup>). Thus it is safe to use, even if your calculations introduce numerical errors.